# Using Google OpenID behind a proxy server

Tags: php, zend-framework, proxy, openid

I have followed this tutorial on Google https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/tutorial_php to create a marketplace app for a school. The code works on my server but when the app is ran from within the school it fails.

The reason it fails is because the school uses a proxy server. Does anyone know how to set a proxy server when using the Zend/Google OpenID code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there are two different ways that the library connects to the internet:

1. using cURL (found in /Yadis/ParanoidHTTPFetcher.php)
2. using sockets (found in /Yadis/PlainHTTPFetcher.php)

As far as I can tell, it defaults to using cURL, as long as it's installed.

There are two curl_init() calls in there, so at some point you need to add:

```
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY, '10.2.68.20');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '3128');
```

Or, whatever your proxy server is. That should do the job!